# Is there a way to reuse a specific test case ( it block ) from a describe block in mocha framework ( using javascript )

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, spectron

I m fairly new to mocha framework , I would like to know if we can reuse a test case from a particular describe block.

```
For example
//Test.js
describe("Reuse code here" , function(){

it("Want to reuse this test case " , function () {
    //do some test here .

})
})

//test1.js
in test1.js can I access the it block of test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just refactor the function being passed to the it into its own function?

E.g
For example

```
//Test.js
describe("Reuse code here" , function(){

    it("Want to reuse this test case " , customReusableFunction)
    
})


function customReusableFunction(){
  // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your response . 
I m adding the refactored functions as test steps , and reuse the whole test case altogether .

Comment: For example :
I have a login test case , which I might need in every suite at the start of execution. I dont want to copy paste the same test case in every test suite . I simply want to reduce the code weight by reusing the test cases itself , instead of just the functions.

Comment: test suite1.js
test suite2.js
test suite3.js
test suite4.js , each suite is in a different file.

I would like to define login test case in a different file , and use this test case ( it block ) in all the 4 test suites.